# Can anyone find a copy of "Notes on secret societies" by C.T. Dobrée on the internet?

Tags: crime, historical-research, research, malaysia

[image]

> "Notes on secret societies, compiled by C.T. Dobrée, is a guide to Chinese triads or secret societies operating in Malaya in the post-war era, with information on the secret codes of language and gestures by which members could identify each other.  This book was compiled as a report for the Federation of Malay Police service in 1953, and printed at the Caxton Press in Kuala Lumpur. Charles Thomas Winston Dobree was appointed Superintendent in the Federation of Malaya Police service in 1948, and at the time of writing was Assistant Commissioner. He appears to have become quite an authority on Chinese gambling syndicates, for he also authored Gambling games of Malaya, printed at the Caxton Press in 1955."

(Source: https://blogs.bl.uk/asian-and-african/2019/06/some-new-old-books-on-and-from-the-malay-world.html)

Comment: It's likely to still be in copyright. However, have a look here. https://www.worldcat.org/title/notes-on-secret-societies/oclc/969536534&referer=brief_results you didn't mention where you are. If you live in the UK, you can get a reader's pass to the British library and read it. You are allowed to photograph up to whatever percentage is permitted under copyright law. If that's not feasible, look into inter library loans wherever you live

Comment: @NeMo Thanks. I can't find it in any libraries or in my area at all, for purchase or borrowing.

Comment: I had a look here: https://www.bookfinder.com which has good reviews for finding books for sale, but didn't find anything by that author. If you do find a copy, it's likely to be very expensive because it's rare. I'd look into inter-library loans - you may have to pay, but much cheaper than buying it. I found 1 review which might give you an idea of the contents: https://www.jstor.org/stable/25188163?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents. You might be able to access this link via a university account (if you have one) or a public library for free.

Comment: BTW, though I think it's misguided, we're not supposed to post reference requests as questions. The stack exchange chat is a good place to do that if you want to - put your question there. Good luck

Comment: @NeMo Thanks so much for the help. I didn't see that rule. I saw that Sources are not encouraged to be asked about, but asking for research resources seemed ok to me, and there are two research tags so I thought it would be normal? I didn't ask here until I really exhausted all my other avenues trying to find this book.

Comment: Can I ask why you want to see this book? Is it for an essay, or what? I don't know anything about the subject, but putting the author and title into google books will get you results which quote from it, and there are bound to be books on similar subjects that are easier to get hold of.

Comment: @NeMo General interest.

Comment: I admire your persistence in trying to hunt it down, and hope you succeed - but you might want to start with a book that's easier to obtain.

Comment: @NeMo Thanks a lot. I've already got other books. It's a fascinating subject and I can be OCD when it comes to getting old sources, hehehe.